# Facebook OAuth shows "you must log in first"

Tags: android, facebook

I want to make MyApp name show on the upper space as Facebook Samples shown.
But even the source code is the same with the sample's, the raw/layout data are the same, too. I don't know why MyApp shows only "You must log in first".

Is anything I missed?

[image: Different from MyApp with FacebookDemo]

Now I put my whole source code up to the share space: http://qfs.mobi/f689673
And I found it seems not login successful if I input the right information.

Comment: What version of the Facebook SDK are you using?

Comment: did u first try to call a facebook api other than login? I guess this error comes, when i try to share a status before i log in fb.

Comment: So can you try the url in your browser and tell me what it shows. The SDK basically uses a webview to point to the url (replace xxx with your app_id: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=xxx&redirect_uri=fbconnect://success

Comment: @RahulParsani: It shows as picture: http://i.imgur.com/F4As96u.png and it shows my app Name right.

Comment: @ParijatBose: I only do Session.openActiveSession().

Comment: Quick question, what screen shows after you enter the correct login information in the original image?

Comment: @RahulParsani: I see nothing after entering the correct login information. No other dialog shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem..

I change to use the Facebook Sample And run with my app_id. And then I found there are error code when login dialog shows. "This app is in sandbox mode."

God! Isn't sandbox mode for "Developers"? Seems I misunderstand..

Answer (score 0):

Since this a problem is with the webpage shown by the facebook sdk, it doesn't seem to be an issue with your android code, but rather with the way your facebook app is defined in the app center.

The SDK basically redirects you to this link: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=xxx&redirect_uri=fbconnect://success (replace xxx with your app_id). Try going to the link when you are not logged in or when you are in incognito mode, you should see the login screen as such: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuAVg.jpg

You could check a couple of things:

1. That your app is live. Check this on your app basic settings page
2. Try changing the language on the login page and see if that helps, since your app is in a language other than English

Comment: Actually I try to login Facebook with my own language. But the login page still shows the same thing. And I found when the user does not open the two-step authentication, there won't show the second dialog as the link: http://i.imgur.com/asMrGr5.png

Answer (score 0):

go in android setting,then Applications,Manage applications,find your browser and clear data,it works as usual!

Comment: I think @timyau is actually looking for a programming solution, not a user solution :)